# Adapt SWT UI elements according to display resolution

Tags: java, user-interface, resize, swt, display

I've written a GUI application, each shell is using `GridLayout`. After writing it for 1280*1024 screen I realized I should make it usable on every display, so I added a method converting the height and width of each element according to display resolution:

```
public static int widthconverter(double x){   
        int width = 0;
        width=(int) ((x/1280.0)*screenWidth);
        return width;
    }
public static int heightconverter(double x){
        int height = 0;
        height=(int) ((x/1024.0)*screenHeight);
        return height;
    }
```

This does not work as I want it to. For example using 800*600 resolution the shell is resized but is a bit too small in width and height to cover all included elements. Going to 4K display it also doesn't work as needed.

Any idea to solve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: As said I am using GridLayout for all shells.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Comment: Sorry, but there was no answer that solved my problem. Thanks for your help anyway. Meanwhile I figured it out by myself:

Comment: No need to resize the fonts, but for the shells and Labels and Textfield I wrote a method converting width and height according screen resolution (see above). The only thing that was missing was a scaling factor accounting for the proportion of width and height(in the case 1280/1024=1.25).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code that solved my problem for anyone having the same problem:

```
static double screenWidth= screen.getWidth(); 
static double screenHeight=screen.getHeight(); 
int pixelPerInch=java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution(); 
static double scalingFactorheight=(screenWidth/screenHeight)/1.25;

public static int widthconverter(double x){
    int width = 0;
    width=(int) ((x/1280.0)*screenWidth);
    return width;
}

public static int heightconverter(double x){
    int height = 0;
    height=(int) ((x/1024.0)*screenHeight*scalingFactorheight);
    return height;
}
```

Comment: From Neon onwards user should not bother with the scaling factor. SWT takes care of that. The sizes specified in SWT/eclipse api are in points(size in pixels/scalefactor). The above code should be required. You'll get aboulutes size in pixels only when you use 100% scalefactor. all the other times its relative to scaling factor of the monitor

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't specify absolute sizes in pixels at all.

In many cases, the size of a control is ruled by its content. Often the dimension of the characters to be shown gives a good base measurement unit. The code snippet below can be used as a template to determine the size of strings in pixels.

```java
Control control = ...
FontData[] fontData = control.getFont().getFontData();
GC gc = new GC( control );
Point size = gc.stringExtent( "Abc" );
// or
int height = gc.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
int avgWidth = gc.getFontMetrics().getAverageCharWidth();
gc.dispose();
```

To determine how many pixels a control will occupy to display a given text, the trim of the control needs to be added. For example

```java
Rectangle trim = control.computeTrim( 0, 0, size.x, size.y );
```

If using a `GridLayout`, the `widthHint` and `heightHint` can be set to the respective fields of the `trim`.

This is a simple approach to design user interfaces to adapt to multiple screen resolutions.

Since the Eclipse 4.6 release, SWT also provides APIs for loading images for high-resolution monitors. If you provide images for different screen resolutions SWT will pick a suitable one. The upper layers like JFace and the Eclipse Platform/UI have also added support for different image resolutions.

See also:

- High-resolution monitor support: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform_isv.php#high-dpi-api
- Understanding SWT Layouts: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html (ignore the deprecation warning, the concepts and API explained there are still valid)
- Computing the preferred size: http://www.codeaffine.com/2016/03/01/swt-scrolledcomposite/ (scroll down to *Computing the Preferred Size ...*)